# how split rows in a new worksheet when I exceed the limit of a worksheet?

Tags: vb.net, export, limit, epplus, worksheet

I'm using Epplus to export data in vb.net to .xlsx file, but what can I do when the rows exceed the limit of the current worksheet? How can I stop the export process to create a new sheet?

This is my code for exporting:

Private Function GeneraExcel(ByVal NombreArchivo As String) As Boolean

```
    Dim file As New System.IO.FileInfo(NombreArchivo)
    Dim Paquete As New OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage(file)
    Dim Hoja As OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorksheet
    Dim columna As Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridColumn
    'numero de columnas de la grilla
    Dim numColumnas As Integer = -1
    For Each columna In grdDatos.Rows.Band.Columns
        If columna.Hidden = False Then
            numColumnas = numColumnas + 1
        End If
    Next

    Hoja = Paquete.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(Globales.TITULO_APLICACION)
    'convirtiendo grilla a datatable
    Dim dtDatos As New DataTable
    dtDatos = TryCast(grdDatos.DataSource, DataTable)
    For i As Integer = 0 To numColumnas
        dtDatos.Columns(i).ColumnName = grdDatos.Rows.Band.Columns(i).Header.Caption
    Next
    'imprimiendo en excel
    Try
        'Insertando título
        Hoja.SelectedRange(4, 2, 4, numColumnas + 1).Merge = True
        Hoja.Cells("B4").Value = "CONSULTA DE IMPORTES"
        Hoja.Cells("B4").Style.HorizontalAlignment = OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Center
        Hoja.Cells("B4").Style.Font.Bold = True
        'Ingresando data con cabeceras
        Hoja.Cells("B6").LoadFromDataTable(dtDatos, True)

        'Colocando formatos 
        Dim colNumber As Integer = 1
        For Each col As Data.DataColumn In dtDatos.Columns
            colNumber += 1
            If (col.DataType) Is GetType(DateTime) Then
                Hoja.Column(colNumber).Style.Numberformat.Format = "dd/mm/yyyy"
            End If
        Next
        Hoja.Cells(Hoja.Dimension.Address).AutoFitColumns()
        Hoja.Row(6).Style.Font.Bold = True
        Hoja.Cells(Hoja.Dimension.Address).Style.Font.Name = "Arial"
        Hoja.Cells(Hoja.Dimension.Address).Style.Font.Size = 8
        'Guardando archivo
        Paquete.SaveAs(file)
        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: I would guess that you will need to manually loop through your DataTable, instead of using LoadFromDataTable, which would allow you to start a new worksheet based on the number of rows written.

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want.  Just take the relevant parts, as the methodology is slightly different from your own....

```
'All lines that begin with an apostrophe (') are remarks and are not
   'required for the macro to run.
   Sub LargeFileImport()

      'Dimension Variables
      Dim ResultStr As String
      Dim FileName As String
      Dim FileNum As Integer
      Dim Counter As Double
      'Ask User for File's Name
      FileName = InputBox("Please enter the Text File's name, e.g. test.txt")
      'Check for no entry
      If FileName = "" Then End
      'Get Next Available File Handle Number
      FileNum = FreeFile()
      'Open Text File For Input
      Open FileName For Input As #FileNum
      'Turn Screen Updating Off
      Application.ScreenUpdating = False
      'Create A New WorkBook With One Worksheet In It
      Workbooks.Add template:=xlWorksheet
      'Set The Counter to 1
      Counter = 1
      'Loop Until the End Of File Is Reached
      Do While Seek(FileNum) <= LOF(FileNum)
         'Display Importing Row Number On Status Bar
          Application.StatusBar = "Importing Row " & _
             Counter & " of text file " & FileName
          'Store One Line Of Text From File To Variable
          Line Input #FileNum, ResultStr
          'Store Variable Data Into Active Cell
          If Left(ResultStr, 1) = "=" Then
             ActiveCell.Value = "'" & ResultStr
          Else
             ActiveCell.Value = ResultStr
          End If

          'For xl97 and later change 16384 to 65536
          If ActiveCell.Row = 15000 Then
             'If On The Last Row Then Add A New Sheet
             ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add
          Else
             'If Not The Last Row Then Go One Cell Down
             ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
          End If
          'Increment the Counter By 1
          Counter = Counter + 1
      'Start Again At Top Of 'Do While' Statement
      Loop
      'Close The Open Text File
      Close
      'Remove Message From Status Bar
      Application.StatusBar = False

   End Sub
```